# Not understanding Storyboard.TargetProperty property

Tags: silverlight-4.0

What exactly is meant by `Storyboard.TargetProperty`? I know that it's the property of the object which we want to animate. But why are they so complex like:

`Storyboard.TargetProperty='(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)'`

and why not:

`Storyboard.TargetProperty='Fill'`

2nd example:

```
 <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).
(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1"
Value="1.88"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Do I need to remember this strange and complex targetproperty? How can I remember the syntax?

Comment: This question is too broad; it currently asks three different questions, arguably all of which are opinion-based (the first one may not be).

Answer (score 0):

Best advice, do this stuff in Blend, My thought is that these animations were never meant to be coded by hand, MS always wanted a designer using Blend to create the UI and Animations while developers wrote the code to push data to it.

Comment: This doesn't answer any of the questions posed by OP.